# how to pass environment variable to the apche2 server

Tags: apache2

I want to pass envrionment varaable to the apcahe2 server...
I have exported `PATH Var` in .bashrc file

now i want to pass it to the server...
I inserted this line '`PassEnv PATH` ' to my apache.conf file..

```
PassEnv PATH
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/abc/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/home/abc/cgi-bin">
            Options +ExecCGI 
            Allow from all

</Directory>
```

but it still not identifying the this variable...

Pl Help me how to pass this Env var to the server..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
```

Should do the trick. The syntax is: *SetEnv* **Key** **Value**

Comment: I want to set 2 Env Var..i.e PATH=/home/abc/blast-2.2.25/bin and BLASTDB=/home/abc/blast-2.2.25/data...but i dnt where to  add these var..i mean in which file i have to add these two var..in apache2.conf or Envvar file????

Comment: httpd.conf is empty.i set these var in apache2.conf..and after that i run the script..bt it showing me error that MSG: cannot find path to blastall....now what should i do.